# How can I delete my question when it is very simple?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

I have come to the conclusion that Stack Exchange websites are for really highly trained professionals dealing with really high tech questions and most of the time, I have the feeling, that simple and primitive questions for new learners are not welcome. Now I have asked this question:

*[Is it possible to know if relation R, is true about two sets of input using neural networks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294310/is-it-possible-to-know-if-relation-r-is-true-about-two-sets-of-input-using-neur)*

And since no answer is given, I think I better remove and come back when I have higher knowledge of neural networks. How can I do that?

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere, even the highly trained professionals...  One thing I dont understand is you saying **since no answer is given** - the question has an answer thats 2 days old, what do you mean?

Comment: Well, yes, but unfortunately, if you read the answer, it says the my question is broad, and that might require very complex solutions, and no solution is given.

Comment: (1/2) I completely agree with the way you're feeling, there is [work going on to fix it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project?cb=1) - I've been through it myself. You just need to write good quality Q's and A's and putting some armour on paper thin skin to feel at home here.

Comment: (2/2)  While the answer is a bit of waffle, its still an answer and your question is very academic so I thought thats what you wanted. No one is going to code you up a solution when you haven't started by showing your code, a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve if you can. Also don't be frightened to ask the user `gung` a follow up question in comments or start an entirely new (yet significantly different) question - this time with code if you want a code solution.

Comment: @JeremyThompson thank you Jeremy, that was very helpful. The point here is that it was more basic curiosity rather than trying to solve a specific problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Stack Exchange websites are for really highly trained professionals dealing with really high tech questions

Nope. There are even school kids who are doing very well on Stack Exchange sites.

Also there are lots and lots of very low quality questions asked on sites, mainly in Stack Overflow. So, you need not worry about it.

The only thing you should care about is, search to ensure your question is not dupe, read how to ask section, provide an MCVE and explain what have you tried so far.

> And since no answer is given, I think I better remove and come back when I have higher knowledge of neural networks

No answer is given is not a reason for deleting a question. There are questions which didn't get a single answer asked years ago.

So, keep it as it is or modify it to make it a good question. Don't delete it.

If you want to delete it, you can use the delete button. But if it has an answer with an upvote, you can't delete it.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, you can't delete your own question if it has an answer with positive score.

Ref: *[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)*

Comment: Thank you so much Jeremy.

Comment: Thank you @PeterMortensen